# A little text game

Tags: java, compiler-errors

I'm a complete java newbie and in my spare time in my computer class the past few days, I've been working on a small game for fun.

My problem is that when I try to compile it, it gives me 16 errors and I'm completely lost on how to fix it, and the only thing that comes to mind is that maybe my code isn't in the correct order. Any help is appreciated, this is my code:

```
/**RULES AND TIPS:
* IF YOU INPUT AN ANSWER THAT IS NOT ONE OF THE CHOICES YOU WILL DIE AND RESTART
* DO NOT LOOK AT THE CODE, IT KILLS THE FUN MY DUDE:/
* SOMETIMES THERE IS MORE THAN ONE CORRECT ANSWER =)
* WEAPONS AND ARMOR WILL AID IN FIGHTING SITUATIONS
********IN PROGRESS RIGHT NOW, WILL ADD THESE ALL SOME DAY********
* ITEM LIST:
* IRON DAGGER +1 STRENGTH
* IRON SWORD +2 STRENGTH
* IRON BROADSWORD +3 STRENGTH
* STEEL DAGGER +2 STRENGTH
* STEEL SWORD +3 STRENGTH
* STEEL BROADSWORD +4 STRENGTH
* MYTHRIL DAGGER +3 STRENGTH
* MYTHRIL SWORD +4 STRENGTH
* MYTHRIL BROADSWORD +5 STRENGTH
* 
* CLOAK +1 DODGE
* MAGIC CLOAK +3 DODGE
*/

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Lame
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    int answer;

    System.out.println("Welcome to Rod's java game");
    System.out.println("Have fun!");
    System.out.println("*****RULES AND TIPS ARE IN THE FIRST AND ONLY COMMENT*****");
    System.out.println("You come to a fork in the road. Which way do you go?");
    System.out.println("Enter 1 for left or 2 for right");
    answer = input.nextInt();

    if (answer == 1)
    {
      Dead();
    }
    if (answer == 2)
    {
      Right();
    }
  }
  public static void Dead()
  {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Wrong decision, you died. Recompile and try a different path!");
  }
  public static void Right()
  {
    int answer1;

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("");
    System.out.println("You walk down the right path and come to a peculiar house.");
    System.out.println("It's getting dark outside and the sign says beware of wolves.");
    System.out.println("Do you stay in the house for the night or sleep under a tree?");
    System.out.println("Enter 1 for the house or 2 for the tree");
    answer1 = input.nextInt();

    if (answer1 == 1)
    {
      House();
    }
    if (answer1 == 2)
    {
      Tree();
    }
  }
  public static void House()
  {
    int answer2;

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("");
    System.out.println("You survived the night and continue your adventure!");
    System.out.println("");
    System.out.println("Beyond the house there is a man being robbed by a thug");
    System.out.println("What do you do?");
    System.out.println("Enter 1 to continue walking or 2 to help him");
    answer2 = input.nextInt();

    if (answer2 == 1)
    {
      Dead1();
    }
    if (answer2 == 2)
    {
      Help();
    }
  }
  public static void Tree()
  {
    int answer4;

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("");
    System.out.println("You survived the night and continue your adventure!");
    System.out.println("");
    System.out.println("Beyond the house there is a man being robbed by a thug");
    System.out.println("What do you do?");
    System.out.println("Enter 1 to continue walking or 2 to help him");
    answer2 = input.nextInt();

    if (answer4 == 1)
    {
      Dead1();
    }
    if (answer4 == 2)
    {
      Help();
    }
    public static void Dead1()
    {
      Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
      System.out.println("As you attempt to continue walking, the thug stops you");
      System.out.println("Before you can say anything, he unsheaths his sword and kills               you!");
      System.out.println("Wrong decision, you died. Recompile and try a different path!");
    }
    public static void Help()
    {
      int answer3;

      Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
      System.out.println("");
      System.out.println("As you run over to help the man, the thug attacks you!");
      System.out.println("You defeat the thug easily, and he drops his Iron Sword!");
      System.out.println("****IRON SWORD OBTAINED****");
      System.out.println("");
      System.out.println("");
      System.out.println("You continue your journey.");
      System.out.println("After a few hours of walking, you get to a dark castle.");
      System.out.println("Your sense of adventure draws you towards the castle");
      System.out.println("You enter, and are immediately greeted by a spiral staircase.");
      System.out.println("Enter 1 to go up the staircase or 2 to continue walking");
      answer3 = input.nextInt();

      if (answer3 == 1)
      {
        Staircase();
      }
      if (answer3 == 2)
      {
        Continuewalking();
      }
     public static void Staircase()
     {
       Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
       System.out.println("You die. The end.");
     }
     public static void Continuewalking()
     {
       Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
       System.out.println("You die. The end.");
     }
    }
  }
}
```

Thanks for the help in advance, I tried to rap up the game quickly so I could get some help :)

Edit: these are the errors I'm getting:

> 16 errors found: File: C:\Users\Rod\Desktop\java files\Lame.java 
>   [line: 116] Error: illegal start of expression File:
>   C:\Users\Rod\Desktop\java files\Lame.java  [line: 116] Error: illegal
>   start of expression File: C:\Users\Rod\Desktop\java files\Lame.java 
>   [line: 116] Error: ';' expected File: C:\Users\Rod\Desktop\java
>   files\Lame.java  [line: 116] Error: ';' expected File:
>   C:\Users\Rod\Desktop\java files\Lame.java  [line: 123] Error: illegal
>   start of expression File: C:\Users\Rod\Desktop\java files\Lame.java 
>   [line: 123] Error: illegal start of expression File:
>   C:\Users\Rod\Desktop\java files\Lame.java  [line: 123] Error: ';'
>   expected File: C:\Users\Rod\Desktop\java files\Lame.java  [line: 123]
>   Error: ';' expected File: C:\Users\Rod\Desktop\java files\Lame.java 
>   [line: 149] Error: illegal start of expression File:
>   C:\Users\Rod\Desktop\java files\Lame.java  [line: 149] Error: illegal
>   start of expression File: C:\Users\Rod\Desktop\java files\Lame.java 
>   [line: 149] Error: ';' expected File: C:\Users\Rod\Desktop\java
>   files\Lame.java  [line: 149] Error: ';' expected File:
>   C:\Users\Rod\Desktop\java files\Lame.java  [line: 154] Error: illegal
>   start of expression File: C:\Users\Rod\Desktop\java files\Lame.java 
>   [line: 154] Error: illegal start of expression File:
>   C:\Users\Rod\Desktop\java files\Lame.java  [line: 154] Error: ';'
>   expected File: C:\Users\Rod\Desktop\java files\Lame.java  [line: 154]
>   Error: ';' expected

Comment: Is this what they mean when they say hard to maintain? ;)

Comment: Stackoverflow is not a spellchecker. Most of your errors can be solved by simply pasting the code in a decent IDE.

Comment: Netbeans will make you see red nightmares until you fix those, and it will more or less tell you a human-readable way of what's wrong there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to define a method (`Dead1`) while still inside another method (`main`).

It doesn't work like that. Start there.

Bear in mind that consistent indentation more or less eliminates silly mistakes like this.

Answer (score 2):

Please use an IDE ([Eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org/%E2%80%8E)? [NetBeans](http://netbeans.org/)?)  to check such errors, even an online tool like [this](http://www.compileonline.com/compile_java_online.php) is enough. **Your approach seems to be too lazy to learn programming.** This is not a good attitude and in general StackOverflow is not meant to check the syntax of your programs but to help solving problems.

Your errors are mostly related to misplaced `}`, check `// <---` comments down here

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Lame
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    int answer;

    System.out.println("Welcome to Rod's java game");
    System.out.println("Have fun!");
    System.out.println("*****RULES AND TIPS ARE IN THE FIRST AND ONLY COMMENT*****");
    System.out.println("You come to a fork in the road. Which way do you go?");
    System.out.println("Enter 1 for left or 2 for right");
    answer = input.nextInt();

    if (answer == 1)
    {
      Dead();
    }
    if (answer == 2)
    {
      Right();
    }
  }
  public static void Dead()
  {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Wrong decision, you died. Recompile and try a different path!");
  }
  public static void Right()
  {
    int answer1;

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("");
    System.out.println("You walk down the right path and come to a peculiar house.");
    System.out.println("It's getting dark outside and the sign says beware of wolves.");
    System.out.println("Do you stay in the house for the night or sleep under a tree?");
    System.out.println("Enter 1 for the house or 2 for the tree");
    answer1 = input.nextInt();

    if (answer1 == 1)
    {
      House();
    }
    if (answer1 == 2)
    {
      Tree();
    }
  }
  public static void House()
  {
    int answer2;

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("");
    System.out.println("You survived the night and continue your adventure!");
    System.out.println("");
    System.out.println("Beyond the house there is a man being robbed by a thug");
    System.out.println("What do you do?");
    System.out.println("Enter 1 to continue walking or 2 to help him");
    answer2 = input.nextInt();

    if (answer2 == 1)
    {
      Dead1();
    }
    if (answer2 == 2)
    {
      Help();
    }
  }
  public static void Tree()
  {
    int answer4;

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("");
    System.out.println("You survived the night and continue your adventure!");
    System.out.println("");
    System.out.println("Beyond the house there is a man being robbed by a thug");
    System.out.println("What do you do?");
    System.out.println("Enter 1 to continue walking or 2 to help him");
    answer4 = input.nextInt(); // <----- CHANGE answer2 to 4

    if (answer4 == 1)
    {
      Dead1();
    }
    if (answer4 == 2)
    {
      Help();
    }
  } // <---- ADD PARENTHESIS HERE
    public static void Dead1()
    {
      Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
      System.out.println("As you attempt to continue walking, the thug stops you");
      System.out.println("Before you can say anything, he unsheaths his sword and kills               you!");
      System.out.println("Wrong decision, you died. Recompile and try a different path!");
    }
    public static void Help()
    {
      int answer3;

      Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
      System.out.println("");
      System.out.println("As you run over to help the man, the thug attacks you!");
      System.out.println("You defeat the thug easily, and he drops his Iron Sword!");
      System.out.println("****IRON SWORD OBTAINED****");
      System.out.println("");
      System.out.println("");
      System.out.println("You continue your journey.");
      System.out.println("After a few hours of walking, you get to a dark castle.");
      System.out.println("Your sense of adventure draws you towards the castle");
      System.out.println("You enter, and are immediately greeted by a spiral staircase.");
      System.out.println("Enter 1 to go up the staircase or 2 to continue walking");
      answer3 = input.nextInt();

      if (answer3 == 1)
      {
        Staircase();
      }
      if (answer3 == 2)
      {
        Continuewalking();
      }
     } // <---- ADD PARENTHESIS HERE
     public static void Staircase()
     {
       Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
       System.out.println("You die. The end.");
     }
     public static void Continuewalking()
     {
       Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
       System.out.println("You die. The end.");
     }
    //} <- REMOVE THEM
  //} <- REMOVE THEM
}
```